# Disable Controls On My Page Displaying in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I've got a page where I'm using `JavaScript` to enable \ disable controls based on what is selected, such as:

```
var selectableItems = document.getElementById('holder_wizard_pnlSelectableItems');
selectableItems.disabled = true;
```

This works perfectly fine in IE, but in Chrome it doesn't do anything.  I did manage to disable the options for a `RadioButtonList` with the code below, but can't seem to translate that into anything else.

```
$("#holder_wizard_pnlContactRequest :input").attr('disabled', true);
```

Ideally what I want to do is disable a button and a drop down list and be able to re-endable them.  There are numerous posts recommending using CSS for this, but that is just a styling change.  I actually want to enable / disable them properly within Chrome.

The controls I want to change the state of are a btnAdd and ddlProducts but nothing I seem to do alters them, then the code I posted adding the attribute didn't change the state of the `button` even though that is also seen as an input.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
document.getElementById("holder_wizard_pnlContactRequest ").setAttribute('disabled', true);
```

Or

```
document.getElementById('btnAdd').disabled='true';
```

Comment: Sorry neither of those work in Chrome.  It is very similar to the code I've already tried from my original post, and it works fine in IE, the issue is for other browsers.